# WCF Proxy Sending Data To Proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

I do simple app like database management and because from server to client.  Here is my method below:

```
public PracownikDane GetPracownik(string imie)
{

    PracownikDane pracownikDane = null;

    using (NORTHWNDEntities database = new
    {
        try
        {
            var query = from pros in database.Employees
                        where pros.Title == imie
                        select pros;
            List<string> pracownicy = new List<string>();

            foreach (var ps in query)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(ps.Title);
                Console.WriteLine(ps.FirstName);
                Console.WriteLine(ps.LastName);
                Console.WriteLine(ps.Address);
            }
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException) 
        {
            string blad="It's an error";
        }
    }

    return pracownikDane;
}
```

And it's shows my this data in server Console like this:
[image]

And here is my code in a client:

```
string pdane = Console.ReadLine();

PracownikDane data = proxy.GetPracownik(pdane);

Console.WriteLine(" ");
Console.WriteLine("Zawód:" + " " + data.Tytul);
Console.WriteLine("Imie:" + " " + data.Imie);
Console.WriteLine("Nazwisko:" + " " + data.Nazwisko);
Console.WriteLine("Kraj Pochodzenia:" + " " + data.Kraj);
Console.WriteLine("Miasto:" + " " + data.Miasto);
Console.WriteLine("Adres:" + " " + data.Adres);
Console.WriteLine("Telefon:" + " " + data.Telefon);
Console.WriteLine("Strona WWW:" + " " + data.WWW);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I would like to know how to put this data in Client.

Comment: Your screenshot isn't showing up (might be my proxy), can you describe the issue you're having?

Comment: It's like that http://pasteboard.co/37KWKI1Sw.jpg